# default_operator parameter in elastisearch query work not correct

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I try send this query :

```
 {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "oracle AND san AND francisco AND hadoop",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false
            }
          },
          "disable_coord": false,
          "adjust_pure_negative": false,
          "boost": 1.1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get total results:
10209

If I add to query "default_operator" parameter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "oracle san francisco hadoop",
              "default_operator": "AND",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": false
            }
          },
          "disable_coord": false,
          "adjust_pure_negative": false,
          "boost": 1.1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get total results:
431.

Maybe some one know what different?

Elastic search version 6.4.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29148#issuecomment-376458216

Comment: In addition, if you add `"explain": true` to your query, you'll see exactly how it is analyzed.

Comment: It return how it scored, but my issue is why number of result's is so different